# WCF service custom response

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-ria-services

I have developed a demo WCF service with basicHttpBinding and I'm getting WCF response as fellow -

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
<s:Body>       
<TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">          
<TestResult>hi Test</TestResult>       
</TestResponse>    
</s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

But I need WCF response in following format-

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
<s:Body>       
-->><t:TestResponse xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/">
<TestResult>hi Test</TestResult>       
</TestResponse>    
</s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

so what can I do to get this reponse??

Comment: ...writing a `Generic Http Handler`... actually your response won't even be valid xml ...

Comment: can't this be achieved by some wcf configuration??

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the two responses you have aren't equivalent: in the first one the <TestResult> element is in the tempuri.org/ namespace, while in the second one it's on the default ("") one (you'd need to prefix TestResult with "t:" as well to maintain the same XML semantics. To accomplish this, there's nothing in WCF which will do it out of the box, but you can change it yourself using one of the many extensibility points of the platform. Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx which deals exactly with that.